# Check many booleans

Tags: c#

I have many Boolean variables as follows:

```
Boolean A;
Boolean B;
Boolean C;
Boolean D;
Boolean E;
Boolean F;
...
```

I would like to make sure all them are false or, at most, only one is true.

Is there a fast way to do this without using a lot of IFs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. Put all of the booleans into a list, and then use the `.All()` or `.Any()` extension methods.

```
var options = new List<bool>{A, B, C, D, E, F, etc.};
var allAreFalse = options.All(b => !b);
var atLeastOneIsTrue = options.Any(b => b);
var moreThanOneIsTrue = options.Where(b => b).Skip(1).Any();
```

PS--It's likely that you don't actually want to declare all of these booleans as separate variables in the first place. Code like that usually indicates that you are representing *data* as *code*, and should be using data structures to represent and manipulate those values.

Comment: This does not answer his question : I would like to make sure all them are false or, at most, only one is true.

Comment: @brz: I figured that question represented two separate requirements, since if only one is true then they're obviously not all false. I show, individually, how to determine whether they are all false, and whether more than one is true. The OP is free to pick and mix from these possibilities as he sees fit.

Comment: Why this many upvotes for a potentially wrong answer? Am I missing the point? @brz's answer is the only right one here.

Comment: Nearly the same as your last but seems to be what OP asked: `bool allFalseOrOneTrue = !bools.Where(b => b).Skip(1).Any();`

Comment: @Mrchief: I think most people (including the OP) recognize that this provides the information that the OP was missing. As I already pointed out, "all false" and "at most one true" are redundant, so it's quite possible that the OP needs to check one of these in one case and another in the other case. By showing how to create the basic building blocks, I enable him (and others with similar questions) to easily adapt these pieces to their needs. For example, to check that one or fewer are true, you can just use `!moreThanOneIsTrue`.

Answer (score 6):

Add them to a list and count the true values:

```
var lst = new[] { A, B, C, D, E };
var res = lst.Count(x=>x) <= 1;
```

Comment: +1 This is the proper and neat way to limit the number of `true` allowed to either zero or once. Another +1 should be given for using `new[]` instead of `List<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean[] bools = new boolean[...];

// add all bools to list

if (!bools.All()) {
    // All are false
}
if (bools.Any()){
    // One or more are true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 unsigned long var64 = (X & A<<1 & B<<2 & C<<3 .... Z <<63)+1
```

makes var64 zero if all true if os and project and cpu is 64 bit x64;

Comment: You probably mean `&` instead of `&&`, and you could mesh them all using the `&` without shifting, really... But that is not entirely what the OP is looking for

Comment: Thanks for the info. Maybe there need to be another data structure to save them (like a single 64 bit long integer)